# In C#, how can I refer to a typedef from a C++/CLI class

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Given the following c++/cli code:

```
public ref class A
{
public:
    typedef System::String B;
};
```

How can I get the following C# code to work:

```
var b = new A.B();
```

EDIT: if it helps, the `typedef` is not a hard requirement. My goal was to end up with a type defined once and usable in both worlds.

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: Also, why would you typedef `System::String`?

Comment: C++/CLI inherits a number of features that are specific to native C++.  Templates are another good example.  But they can't be expressed in .NET metadata, that's where the buck stops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# doesn't have typedefs.  It does have a form of type aliases made with using declarations, but those don't support your usage (the type alias has to be repeated in every file where it is used, it isn't carried with the containing type).

It's very rare for a language to support consuming a feature from another language, that the first doesn't itself support.  And, no surprise, C# doesn't support typedefs declared in C++/CLI any more than it supports typedefs declared in C#.

If you have code that needs this feature, write it in C++/CLI, and call it from C#.

Comment: I was willing to hear even hairbrained solutions but, alas, if it's not meant to be, then, so be it. Green check because that's the answer. (At some point I even tried something like `ref class B : public System::String {};` but `System::String` is `sealed`!)